# Where to ask question about google maps

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I've got a curiosity about google maps. I found in some areas of the regular roadmap, they use a different color schemes. I'd like to know why. Where would such a question be appropriate?

There are many sites on the network nowadays, and probably I'm overlooking. Is there a site for the "curiosities of the internet" or a "why is it the way it is?"

I've seen some questions like this on skeptics, retro computing, life hacks. But none of them with something "common" like this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are three possible sites for questions about Google Maps, depending on what method you're using to access the service:

- If you're accessing Google Maps from a **web browser**, you'll want to ask it on [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/)
- If you're accessing it from the Google Maps app on an **Android device**, you'll want to ask it on [Android Enthusiasts Stack Exchange](https://android.stackexchange.com/)
- If you're accessing it from the Google Maps app on an **iOS device**, you'll want to ask it on [Ask Different (Apple) Stack Exchange](https://apple.stackexchange.com/)

---

Be sure to read the corresponding site's help center before posting:

https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help
https://android.stackexchange.com/help
https://apple.stackexchange.com/help